# Condition that decides whether to execute WHERE or not

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, where-clause

I have a really big stored procedure and I'd like to include a `WHERE` clause at the end to be executed just in case that `@myparameter=1`. I don't want the stored procedure to pay any attention to the WHERE clause when `@myparameter=0`. Is there any way to do this with `CASE` or something like that?

Comment: Thank you for your answers. What I finally did was somthing like this:
'code'
SELECT *
FROM mytable 
where mytable.Archive = (CASE
    WHEN @myparameter=1
          THEN 1       
    ELSE mytable.Archive END)
'code'
This way I'll get all data when @myparameter=0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE @myparameter=0 OR (insert the current conditions here)
```

Answer (score 0):

add a modified version of where instead of yours

```
where (@myparemeter = 0 or (@myparameter = 1 and (your where conditions here)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers. What I finally did was somthing like this:

SELECT *
FROM mytable 
where mytable.Archive = (CASE
    WHEN @myparameter=1
          THEN 1       
    ELSE mytable.Archive END)
 
This way I'll get all data when @myparameter=0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use CASE, something like this ...

```
WHERE
  CASE 
    WHEN (@myparameter=0) THEN 1
    WHEN (@myparameter=1) AND (rest of where clause) THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END = 1
```